# Adding own short code to vc_custom_heading

Tags: wordpress, wpbakery

Wondering if there is any way to render my shortcode inside Custom Heading.

I see that wpBakery allows us to do shortcode mapping, but that is actually not what I want.

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: a workaround could be inserting the shortcode directly inside a post or page, and then select that post/page as "text source" in your custom heading.

Comment: @GrafiCode thanks for the answer, when selected option post/page -  don't see the option to select any post? are you sure that suppose to work the way you described it?

Comment: oh sorry, my bad, I thought it was able to get the post/page body, when that option is actually about the post/page TITLE